# KnockoutJS filter by specific property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, filter

I use KnockoutJS for a job application website using the getJSON-method in JS.

Unfortunately, I get this structure:

- offices

  - new york

    - departments

      - finance

        - jobs

          - example
          - ...
      - IT
      - logistics
      - marketing
  - washington

    - departments

      - finance
      - IT
      - logistics
      - marketing
  - los angeles

    - departments

      - finance
      - IT
      - logistics
      - marketing

I use the `filter`-function in JS to filter out some cities' office which are not open yet, which works well.

**But now I need to filter out all departments *except logistics***, because I want to show only logistic jobs for a specific city. I want it to be dynamically, so it will only show **logistics** even if there are more departments to come.

I can't find a good solution to this. Any ideas?

**Edit: Here is the dummy JSON:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to create a handler ? can you share your code with dummy JSON ?

Comment: I tried many things, but the problem seems to be the deep nested JSON structure. The `filter`-function would work if it wasn't nested so deep. I will share my code in a moment.

Comment: @AmitBhoyar Now you can see the JSON structure.

Comment: 1) Please create a [mcve]. Your code/json should be in the question and [not an image of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). We can't copy an image to create an answer. 2) What are the inputs and outputs? Inputs are department name and city name and output is list of jobs? Please create a minimal snippet or jsfiddle of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in jobs, I'd suggest to make a `Job` model that merges the data currently defined only by structure in to one handy object.

To flatten your data, you perform a set of `reduce` actions:

```js
const jobData={offices:[{location:"ny",departments:[{name:"Logistics",jobs:[{title:"driver for x"},{title:"driver for y"}]},{name:"Finance",jobs:[{title:"CFO"}]}]},{location:"la",departments:[{name:"Logistics",jobs:[{title:"driver for z"}]},{name:"IT",jobs:[{title:"tech support manager"}]}]}]}


const Job = (title, department, officeLocation) => ({
  title,
  department,
  officeLocation
});

const JobList = ({ offices }) => ({
  jobs: offices.reduce(
    (allJobs, { location, departments }) => departments.reduce(
      (allJobs, { name, jobs }) => jobs.reduce(
        (allJobs, { title }) => allJobs.concat(
          Job(title, name, location)
        ),
        allJobs
      ),
      allJobs
    ),
    []
  )
})

console.log(JobList(jobData))
```

Now that we have our data format sorted out, we can start writing the knockout code.

I've created a `table` that renders a computed list of jobs. In the computation, we filter on 2 properties: a required office, and a required department.

The filters itself are "flat", because the `Job` object has al the data we need. E.g., the Logistics Filter can be applied like:

```
const logisticsJobs = ko.pureComputed(
  jobList().filter(job => job.department === "logistics")
);
```

Here's the example. Use the `<select>` elements in the table header to apply filters.

```js
function JobFinder() {
  const jobData = ko.observable({ offices: [] });
  const jobList = ko.pureComputed(
    () => JobList(jobData())
  );
  
  // Lists of properties we can filter on
  this.offices = ko.pureComputed(
    () => uniques(jobList().map(job => job.officeLocation))
  );
  
  this.departments = ko.pureComputed(
    () => uniques(jobList().map(job => job.department))
  );
  
  // Filter values
  this.requiredOffice = ko.observable(null);
  this.requiredDepartment = ko.observable(null);
  
  // Actual filter logic
  const officeFilter = ko.pureComputed(
    () => this.requiredOffice()
      ? job => job.officeLocation === this.requiredOffice()
      : () => true
  );
  
  const departmentFilter = ko.pureComputed(
    () => this.requiredDepartment()
      ? job => job.department === this.requiredDepartment()
      : () => true
  );
  
  const allFilters = ko.pureComputed(
    () => [ officeFilter(), departmentFilter() ]
  )
  
  const filterFn = ko.pureComputed(
    () => job => allFilters().every(f => f(job))
  )
  
  // The resulting list
  this.filteredJobs = ko.pureComputed(
    () => jobList().filter(filterFn())
  );

  // To load the data (can be async in real app)
  this.loadJobData = function() {
    jobData(getJobData());
  }
};

// Initialize app
const app = new JobFinder();
ko.applyBindings(app);
app.loadJobData();


// utils
function uniques(xs) { return Array.from(new Set(xs)); }


// Code writen in the previous snippet:
function getJobData() { 
  return {offices:[{location:"ny",departments:[{name:"Logistics",jobs:[{title:"driver for x"},{title:"driver for y"}]},{name:"Finance",jobs:[{title:"CFO"}]}]},{location:"la",departments:[{name:"Logistics",jobs:[{title:"driver for z"}]},{name:"IT",jobs:[{title:"tech support manager"}]}]}]};
};


function Job(title, department, officeLocation) {
  return {
    title,
    department,
    officeLocation
  }
};

function JobList({ offices }) {
  return offices.reduce(
    (allJobs, { location, departments }) => departments.reduce(
      (allJobs, { name, jobs }) => jobs.reduce(
        (allJobs, { title }) => allJobs.concat(
          Job(title, name, location)
        ),
        allJobs
      ),
      allJobs
    ),
    []
  )
};
```

```css
th { 
  text-align: left;
  width: 30% 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <select data-bind="
          options: offices,
          value: requiredOffice,
          optionsCaption: 'Show all locations'">
        </select>
      </th>
        <th>
        <select data-bind="
          options: departments,
          value: requiredDepartment,
          optionsCaption: 'Show all departments'">
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredJobs">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: officeLocation"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: department"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer. I will try it out.